# What does "JavaFX Charts API is a visual centric" mean?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

In JavaFX's documentation, oracle has mentioned that:

> JavaFX Charts API is a visual centric API rather than model centric.

What does it mean exactly? what is the definition of `visual centric API` and `model centric api`?

Oracle's link can be found from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/chart/package-summary.html) and If it is possible describe it with an example.

Comment: It just means it's intended to work with visual representations and not abstract data model objects.  There's no formal definition of "visual centric", it's just the personal choice of phrase by the author of the Javadoc.